# Excel formula to handle cell's custom format

Tags: excel, formula

I have the constraint of not being allowed to use user defined functions or a macro so I need to find a solution with a formula in Excel.

I have cells in the following format: 
source cell: (i.e. *2.3q* - in custom format **0.0"q"**)

[image]

I need a formula that will change the decimal point to a decimal comma so that I get the following:
target cell: (i.e. *2,3q*)

[image]

It sounds easy but I am afraid it is not even possible :(

Edit: My problem is only with the Custom format as this is easily solved for the General format cells. But my source column also has normal General numeric values. So as someone in the comments asked about it, here is a better illustration of the source (left) and the desired target (right) columns (the cells without the q flag are in General normal format, and those with the q flag are in the **0.0"q"** custom format):

[updated illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lO4B.jpg)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188890/discussion-on-question-by-papen-excel-formula-to-handle-cells-custom-format).

Comment: I see - there are other populated columns but it does not seem that there is a connection to them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use substitute() like this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(C1,".",",",1)
```

[image]

Comment: This does not work - it does not transfer the "q". Seems like your source cell is not in the given custom format (0.0"q")

Comment: Then perhaps you should format the target cell to the same format... I have only general formatting on both cells - the source cell contains "2.3q" no more no less.

Comment: This is not an option. The problem is that I do not know in advance which are the cells that are in this format. This is a template and it populates most of the cells with normal values, i.e. 2.3 only. Some cells will have the q flag attached to the number value and only they are extracted in the custom format and there is no way I would know in advance which are these cells. Maybe there is a formula that can recognize the the source cell is in a custom format? Then it can be combined with the SUBSTITUTE solution. But to this moment I have found any..

Answer (score 0):

If the only custom format is `0.0 q`, then:

```
=IF(CELL("format",A1)="G",A1,SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A1,"0.0 q"),".",","))
```

Be aware that if you change the format of `A1`, you will have to do a recalculation in order to get the result of the `CELL` function to update.